# How to get first cell of TableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cell, uitableview

I'm new in Objective-C and iOS develop and I have a strange problem, only in one specific situation. This is part of my switch code:

```
if(nowSolo>-1){
    [soloarray replaceObjectAtIndex:nowSolo withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:nowSolo inSection:0];
    CustomCell *cell2=[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowSolo];
    cell2.solo.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.29 green:0.67 blue:0.62 alpha:1.0];
}
nowSolo=row;
[soloarray replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
cell.solo.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.13 green:0.41 blue:0.37 alpha:1.0];
```

Everything goes fine but when variable **nowSolo** is equal 0 then `cell2 = null`. I don't understand why, because for other values like 1,2,3 etc it work correctly.

Comment: when you want to get the cell ?

Comment: you are using `cell` outside of if condition. what is it ?

Comment: update your question with proper code (method)

Comment: Can you explain what you need to achieve ?? cell selection or something else ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the cell inside both methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath` & `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like when you configuring it or when you touch.

Get specific cell when you configuring inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method like below code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        // configure cell here 
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Get specific cell when you touch using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method see below code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     if (indexPath.row == 0) {
          // do specific action on first cell 
     }
}
```